# Does multiplying range affect accuracy of an analog to digital converter?

Tags: microcontroller, adc

Suppose the built in analog to digital converter of a microcontroller has an operating voltage of 0-5 V. These values are converted to integers ranging from 0-1023. So the resolution is 5/1024.

I want to measure an analog value ranging from 0-1 V.

If I multiply the analog value by 5 in a microcontroller that reads the value (using the multiplication operator in software,) will the resolution be 1/1024?

Comment: Think about it: what value would you have to read from the ADC, in order to get a value of 1/1024 after multiplying? It would have to be 0.2. But the ADC can't measure 0.2, only 0 or 1. After you multiply you can get 0 or 5, but you can't get 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *If I multiply the analog value by 5 in a microcontroller that reads
> the value (using the multiplication operator in software), will the
> resolution be 1/1024?*

No the resolution will be one-fifth of that at best. 1 volt applied to a 10-bit ADC with 5 volt input full-scale will result in a digital number of 204. That has a resolution of 1 in 204 or 0.49% and will remain at 0.49% even when you multiply up 204 by 5.

<sub>Be aware that gain errors and offset errors in the ADC means you can't truly use the full 0 to 5 volt input of an ADC. Maybe 98% of it but not 100%.</sub>

<sub>Many ADCs can work at a much lower reference voltage and this of course might help you get a better solution.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The resolution in volts is the reference voltage of the analog to digital converter (ADC) divided by the number of counts from the ADC.

The input voltage of the signal isn't involved.

Given a 10 bit ADC (1024 counts) and a 5V reference voltage for the ADC, the voltage resolution is 5V/1024 = 4.8828125 millivolts per count.

Your input signal of maximum 1V would generate a maximum count of 204 from the ADC.

If you need 1V/1024 resolution, then you have a couple of options:

1. Use an opamp to multiply the input signal by 5 before it goes to the ADC
2. Use a reference voltage of 1V for the ADC.

Both options have disadvantages.

For example, the opamp solution can add noise and offset to your signal.  Using a lower reference voltage depends on having a clean enough (and accurate enough) reference voltage available - and your ADC must have a connection for an external reference.